# Help to roll back, restore, or undo function key maybe!

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, cursor, function-keys

Mouse cursor has turned to a big X and I have no sidebars!  like its full screened! only have desktop icons! can't do anything! No top, left, or bottom sidebars that I had before! I moved the computer and something fell onto the keyboard and now this is happening!

Comment: Could have reinstalled operating system in the time have spent researching already!  But really don't want to lose files if simple fix!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We'll need a bit more detail in order to help you.  Would you please expand your question to include your Ubuntu version and distribution?  Also, when you say you can't do anything, do you mean that you cannot open anything?  If you restart the computer, does it return to normal?

Comment: I have restarted many times, newest desktop version Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS !  I can right click and get couple options (command prompt) which I know very little about, but mainly have no access to the sidebars which are basically everything!  Including programs,tools and internet! Next time I will add all icons to the desktop for everything!

Comment: Matthew, check out [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/527350) by Oli.  Does it help at all?

Comment: If I could just roll it back 2 days would that work?  I've updated it almost daily!

Comment: If your configs were backed up, then yes, that ought to work.

Comment: I gave up! Tried many things, can't find whatever this unity they talk about, have tried entering everything mentioned in terminal and still same issue. Installing different harddrive and installing Ubuntu again to try! Will make problem drive the slave and recover available data that way!